# wc3270 script file inserting user input

Tags: terminal-emulator, 3270

I would like to know how to insert scripted user inputs into the wc3270 emulated environment. An example is the inserting of the "tso" command and then automating login process for user.

Below is a script I wrote that doesn't seem to load the string when needed.

```
connect(192.168.10.102:23)
ascii()
String tso
```

Are there ways to input user strings ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe need read the [manual user](http://x3270.bgp.nu/Unix/x3270-script.html) for do that.

In your example `String tso` send `tso` to actual position cursor, if the cursor are placed in bad site or not in input site, then that not work.

You can use `MoveCursor` for correct the cursor position.